# What is the equivalent query of sails "contains" in mongodb?

Tags: sql, regex, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

Hi I have this query in sails...

```
 Model.find().where({ seachField : { contains:"search_key" }}).exec(cb);
```

Total Rows return: 20

When I'm trying to convert it to node, I used the query instead

```
 db.get().collection("model").find({ seachField : { '$regex' : ".*"+searchKey+".*"}}).toArray()...
```

Total Rows return: 10

May I know what is the "contains" function equivalent to mongoDB so I could get the same number of results?

Appreciate your help!

Thank you

Comment: Neither of those statements should be valid. The syntax should be ` "field": { contains: "search_key" }` or plain mongo `"field": { "$regex": "search_key" }` where "field" is the field to search. I would also suggest the the problem possibly lies with the `or` instead.

Comment: hi Neil thanks for your comment. Oh yeah I forgot the search field :) thanks for correcting... Both of them working fine the only difference is the results has different count. I figured it out few hours ago, I just added { "$regex" : ".*"+searchKey+".*", "$options":'i' } for case insensitive search :)

Answer (score 0):

Its:

```
db.model.find({ seachField : new RegExp(searchKey)}).toArray()
```

It you familiar with SQL this is very helpful: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/